# How to add functions to a plugin in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a plugin named react-native-masonry-list to show the list of data in masonry view which works fine.But when i try to update a value in the data.The value gets updated but it is not reflected in the masonry list.I have checked the props in which the data gets updated.

When i saw the code in the plugin it has mentioned that only during the image / orientation / size gets changed the data is refreshed and state gets updated.

I would like to add a function like once the data gets changed it should  refresh the list.But i don't know how to inherit the plugin without making any changes in their code.

Plugin Link:  [react-native-masonry-list](https://github.com/Luehang/react-native-masonry-list)

```
<MasonryList
  sorted={true}
  imageContainerStyle={styles.masonryImgView}
  onPressImage={this.onSelectBranchItem}
  renderIndividualHeader={res => {
    return (
      <DealsMasonryHeader
        data={res}
        onSelectedDeal={this.onSelectedDeal}
        onSelectedFavourite={this.onSelectedFavourite.bind(this, res)}
        favDisable={res.isfavourite}
        onMapOpen={this.onMapOpen.bind(this, res)}
        onSocialShare={this.socialShare.bind(this, res)}
      />
    );
  }}
  renderIndividualFooter={res => {
    return (
      <DealsMasonryFooter
        data={res}
        onItemPress={this.onSelectBranchItem.bind(this, res)}
      />
    );
  }}
  images={filterData}
/>
```

FilterData:

```
const { dealsList, currentUser } = this.props;
const { searchText, selectedBranchItem } = this.state;
let re = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
const filterData = dealsList
  ? dealsList.filter((deal) => {
    return !!(
      deal.title.match(re) ||
        deal.discount_percentage.toString().match(re) ||
        deal.tags.toString().match(re)
    );
  })
  : [];
```

I want to know whether it is possible to inherit a component in react native

In the react-native-masonry-list plugin -> MasonryList.js

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.layoutDimensions.width && nextProps.layoutDimensions.height &&
        nextProps.layoutDimensions.columnWidth && nextProps.layoutDimensions.gutterSize &&
        nextProps.layoutDimensions.width !== this.props.layoutDimensions.width &&
        nextProps.layoutDimensions.height !== this.props.layoutDimensions.height &&
        !this.props.containerWidth) {
            this.resolveImages(
                nextProps.itemSource,
                nextProps.images,
                nextProps.layoutDimensions,
                nextProps.columns,
                nextProps.sorted
            );
    }
    else if (nextProps.orientation !== this.props.orientation ||
        nextProps.columns !== this.props.columns ||
        nextProps.spacing !== this.props.spacing ||
        nextProps.sorted !== this.props.sorted ||
        nextProps.containerWidth !== this.props.containerWidth) {
            this.resolveImages(
                nextProps.itemSource,
                this._calculatedData,
                nextProps.layoutDimensions,
                nextProps.columns,
                nextProps.sorted
            );
    }
    else if (nextProps.images !== this.props.images) {
        this.resolveImages(
            nextProps.itemSource,
            nextProps.images,
            nextProps.layoutDimensions,
            nextProps.columns,
            nextProps.sorted
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does you `resolveImages` method look like? It's hard to say what might be wrong without seeing how you are updating your `filterData`.

Comment: @Tholle i didn't add all the codes here from the plugin.If u can take a look at the plugin it would be easier
In the react-native-masonry-list plugin -> MasonryList.js

Comment: Yes, you don't have to include any library code, but how *you* are updating your `filterData` variable is very important.

Comment: @Tholle i have added the filterData can you pls check it